# PHP: Eliminar duplicados ARRAY

Tags: php, array

Tengo armado un array de este tipo:

```
$array =array('epc' => "$tag",);
```

Al hacer un print de $array obtengo lo siguiente:

> Array ( [epc] => 1792 ) Array ( [epc] => 1792 ) Array ( [epc] => 1212 ) Array ( [epc] => 1792 ) Array ( [epc] => 1792 ) Array ( [epc] => 1212 ) Array ( [epc] => 1792 ) Array ( [epc] => 1212 ) Array ( [epc] => 1792 ) Array ( [epc] => 1792 ) Array ( [epc] => 1792 ) Array ( [epc] => 1792 ) Array ( [epc] => 1792 ) Array ( [epc] => 1792 ) Array ( [epc] => 1212 ) Array ( [epc] => 1792 ) Array ( [epc] => 1792 )

Estoy buscando obtener como resultado únicamente los valores diferentes sin repetir es decir: 1792 y 1212

He probado utilizar métodos como array_unique, serialize, foreach y no he obtenido resultado, siempre veo todos los resultados.

El valor lo obtengo de la lectura de una línea de texto de un TXT.

```
$linea = fgets($fp1); 
$campo = explode(" ", $linea); 
$tag = $campo[1]; 
$tag = str_replace('"','',$tag); 
$tag =(string)(int)$tag;
```

Comment: Todos tienen el valor de 1792 al parecer. Es normal que le muestre todos los elementos, quizá podría añadir los métodos o método que no arroja los resultados esperados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No me parece buena idea *transportar*  un montón de datos para luego desecharlos, sobre todo si estás trabajando con un array voluminoso. Es decir, si tienes que enviar el array a otro sitio para luego borrar los duplicados... no es buena idea.

Puedes crear un array totalmente limpio en el origen y luego enviarlo donde quieras.

A mí particularmente no me gusta la forma desordenada en que `array_unique` construye el nuevo array.

Esta es una posibilidad.

He imaginado que tu línea es así:

```
"1792" "1792" "1212" "1792"
```

Vamos a limpiarla, quitando las `"`

Como quieres valores enteros, aplicaremos esto:

```
$arrEnteros = array_map('intval', explode(' ', $strLimpia));
```

Usaremos una estrategia con [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-count-values.php) el cual crea un array con las ocurrencias de cada valor. (Sería como hacer la función de `array_unique`.

```
$arrUnicos = array_count_values($arrEnteros);
```

Y crearemos nuestro array final, **totalmente limpio y ordenado**, con las claves `epc` y como valor las antiguas claves de `$arrUnicos`.

---

### Código

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/JJVEK28346)**</kbd>

```
$linea = '"1792" "1792" "1212" "1792"';
$strLimpia=str_replace('"','',$linea);
$arrEnteros = array_map('intval', explode(' ', $strLimpia));
$arrUnicos = array_count_values($arrEnteros);
$arrFinal=array();
foreach ($arrUnicos  as $key => $value)  {
    $arrFinal[]=array("epc"=>$key);
}

print_r($arrFinal);
echo "VIENDO EL var_dump()";
var_dump($arrFinal);
?>
```

---

### Resultado

El array se vería así:

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [epc] => 1792
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [epc] => 1212
        )

)
```

Con el var_dump podemos apreciar que se crea con tipos de datos enteros:

```
VIENDO EL var_dump()

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["epc"]=>
    int(1792)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["epc"]=>
    int(1212)
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo y la respuesta!

Answer (score 1):

Podrias hacer algo asi:

array_unique — Elimina valores duplicados de un array

```
$array = array('epc' => "$tag",);
$resultado = array_unique($array);
print_r($resultado);
```